# VSCode not displaying string exponents in integrated terminal on windows

Tags: windows, terminal, visual-studio-code, exponent

When I run a dotnet core app in vscode on windows (using 1.10.2) the integrated terminal does not print out the superscript characters properly.

I am testing it with this string:

`Console.WriteLine("Here is an exponent \xB2");`

The screenshot shows that git bash has no problem, but when git bash is set as the integrated terminal like this:

`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",`

It has no joy - has anyone run into this issue?

Powershell has no joy either when it is set as a internal and external terminal.

On the mac it works no problem - so it is a windows issue, just don't know how to fix it :-)

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sounds like the integrated terminal doesn't do UTF-8.

Comment: Seems to be the case - Any idea on a workaround? Is there a command that will allow it work. Even if it is done every time I launch the terminal?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10519#issuecomment-240178764

Comment: Got it - cheers :-)